# Which temperature does the thermal zone temperature sensors measure?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have created a powershell script that gets the temperature information using the typeperf "\Thermal Zone Information*()\Temperature" command and have parsed the result into a json string as follows:

```
{
    "TZ.EXTZ":  45.850000000000023,
    "TZ.GFXZ":  -0.14999999999997726,
    "TZ.CHGZ":  -273.15,
    "TZ.LOCZ":  -273.15,
    "SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC0.HEPZ":  -71.149999999999977,
    "TZ.BATZ":  33.850000000000023,
    "TZ.CPUZ":  63.850000000000023
}
```

I'm guessing TZ.CPUZ is the cpu temp but about the others I'm not sure what temperature do they measure. By the way I have converted the Kelvin values into Celsius.

Comment: I suspect it's motherboard/sensor-specific - my Dell laptop only finds a single counter instance `TZ.THM` (which records the temperature for a single zone sensor in Kelvin)

Comment: Thanks for the insight. But may I ask if you know what THM stands for in your case?

Comment: My best guess is it's short for "Thermal Heat Monitor" or something generic like that, but I honestly don't know :)

Comment: Thank you for this information. Yeah I guess it is really hard to know esp. when it differs in every pc/laptop brand